# python - remove directory and subfolders with shutil.rmtree - str object not callable

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to remove a directory and I guess i'm having an issue with defining the path for the `shutil.rmtree()`. Does this function take the relative path or the absolute. I use win10 and am having problem understanding how the paths can and should be defined in python, because it seems that for every function the path needs to be defined in a different way.

```
import shutil
dir_to_remove = "C:\\Users\name_of_user\\dir_to remove"
shutil.rmtree(dir_to_remove)
```

Result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-257-9cc5f9fe51d2>", line 1, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(dir_to_remove)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I am able to remove my dir using below code                                          
dir_to_remove = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\test"
shutil.rmtree(dir_to_remove)                                                                                                                                                Are you missing "\" could be like this dir_to_remove = "C:\\Users\\name_of_user\\dir_to remove"

Comment: The error message looks like you somehow managed to overwrite the `rmtree` function. As such, this seems unreproducible. What is the output of `print(type(shutil.rmtree))` and `prit(shutil.rmtree)`?

Comment: If you can reproduce this with the same traceback without the backslash error, please [edit] so we can reopen. We'd like to see a [mre].

Comment: the function has been overwritten. I didn't know this is possible in Python, to overwrite a function from a package. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the second backslash after `C:\\Users`.

```
dir_to_remove = "C:\\Users\\name_of_user\\dir_to remove"
shutil.rmtree(dir_to_remove)
```

Comment: @tripleee, I am assuming it will have an import statement, I just provided the pseudo-code. There are missing "\" in the original statement..

Comment: Good catch, but that would not explain the mystery traceback.